# How many nodes should I have in the last layer of neural network for binary classification?

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I believed that, if I have a `binary-classification` problem then I should *always* have only 1 node in the last layer, since the last layer has to decide about the classification. However, in the following code it is not true.

Let's download the **pizza/steak datasets** (image dataset) and prepare the data using the `ImageDataGenerator`:

```
import zipfile
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0, resnet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

!wget https://storage.googleapis.com/ztm_tf_course/food_vision/pizza_steak.zip
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile("pizza_steak.zip", "r")
zip_ref.extractall()
zip_ref.close()

train_directory = './pizza_steak/train/'
test_directory = './pizza_steak/test/'
IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)

image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                                          zoom_range=0.2,
                                          shear_range=0.2,
                                          rotation_range=0.2)

train_dt = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=train_directory,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE)

test_dt = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=test_directory,
                                                   class_mode='categorical',
                                                   batch_size=32,
                                                   target_size=IMAGE_SIZE)
```

and then build, compile a neural-network and fit the data on it:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dt,
          epochs=5,
          validation_data=test_dt,
          validation_steps=len(test_dt)
```

As you can see the `val_accuracy` is not better than 0.5000, which is very bad!

And now if you just change the last layer to `model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))` and run the same model with 2 nodes in the last layer, you will end up with a far better result, such as `val_accuracy: 0.8680`.

How should know, how many nodes should I have in the last layer when I have a `binary-classification` model?

Comment: The problem is that you set class_mode to categorical, this means your binary label is one-hot encoded into a two element vector (two classes), that is why a single neuron does not work. You could just change the class mode to binary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dr.Snoopy, i add an answer here jut to complete the question.

The point is how do we label our data using the `image_data_generator.flow_from_directory()`.

If we set the `class_mode='categorical'` then the target is **ONE_HOT** and the number of nodes in the last layer is equal to  "**number of classes of target feature**". In my case, it is a binary feature, so i need to have 2 nodes in the last layer.

However, if we use `class_mode='binary'` then the target is indexed and we can have only one node in the last layer.